Title: How to Resolve "File Not Generated" Error in SQLynx Export Function?
I encountered an issue while exporting data using SQLynx: no matter whether I choose to export to Excel, CSV, or SQL files, I consistently receive an error stating:

File Not Generated.

I have attempted multiple re-exports, ensured the file path is correct and free of special characters, but the problem persists.
1.Verified export settings and file paths.
2.Restarted SQLynx and retried the export.
3.Checked operating system permissions to ensure write access to the target folder.
4.Tried changing the export format to different file types, such as switching from Excel to CSV.
I expect to successfully export data files that can be opened and utilized. I am seeking solutions to resolve this issue or insights into possible causes of this error.

I'm not sure what support we can give you based on such a generic error message. You need to obtain some more specific error message or ask this question at their product support forum. Please do not use irrelevant tags for your questions. This question is about a specific development environment, not about any database product.
